# Retrieving Records with Multiple keys. OPENJPA

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa, rpgle

On the language that I know, RPG... You can use multiple keys and find retrieve the values of the record.

Like for table. I can select keys lolo and apple to retrieve the value of sex witch is F. Howerver I could not find some functionality that is like this in OPENJPA.. find() can only use one key? Is there something like find(names.class,:"LOLO","Apple") where keys are F_NAME and L_NAME?

```
Names
F_NAME   L_NAME   Sex
LOLO     Apple     F

Ben      Coke      M
```

While reading jpa, usually the table has P_ID

```
P_ID     F_NAME  L_NAME  Sex
1        LOLO     Apple   F 
2        Ben      Coke    M
```

To retrieve the record lolo apple, i need to use this code..

```
Names name = em.find(Names.class, 1);
```

How will you know the sex if the given value is F_NAME? and L_NAME? In SQL you can just say select * from Names where F_NAME = Lolo , L_NAME = "Apple" and it will output

```
P_ID     F_NAME  L_NAME  Sex
1        LOLO     Apple   F
```

From that you can say that Sex = F.
Like i want to know if lolo apple is male or female, I will search lolo apple on the database... not P_ID = 1. How would i konw what is the P_ID of Lolo Apple.

Hopefully you get what I mean.. Thanks.

Or maybe in another part of the equation, on JPA, how to you retrieve the record to be updated while not knowing yet the P_ID (Primary key) like you only know the first name and last name?

Comment: What I see in the sample is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [OpenJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/apache-openjpa-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT/docs/docbook/manual/main.html)  it defines a JPA Query Language [JPQL].  Wouldn't that be the place to start?

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to specify several key values, why not just specify them in the WHERE clause in JPQL, like you would do in SQL.

```
SELECT ...
  WHERE colX = val1 and colY = val2 and colZ = val3
```

Comment: @wattenT Do you mean that find() method only allows one key? witch is the primary? so if my key is like first name and last name.. There is no way to retrieve it using find(class,firstname , lastname).. You need to do jpql then find(class,P_ID) to populate the entity?

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL, which for example could be embedded in your RPG programs?  It looks to me that JPQL is similar. I would imagine the intent of the JPA design is that you use it with the JPQL, along the same lines as embedded SQL in RPG, rather than modeled after RPG native I/O.  However this is based only on a cursory overview of documentation, I have no direct experience with it, so please verify this further.  I did not delve into details of how JPQL works,  or whether there might be any issues using it on DB2 for i.

Comment: Yeah, I also use sql in rpg.. I'm just wondering if their is a method in JPA related to the CHAIN() in RPG where you can use many keys and placed it on the keylist. Then from their, can retrieve a record..

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/evferlsh270.htm

Maybe I just need to use JPQL to retrieve the record and then use find() to populate the entity then merge() to update da record.

Comment: My point is that [CHAIN](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzasd%2Fsc092508914.htm) does not seem to be the intended mindset to approach this with. My impression is that one would use JPQL to SELECT with whatever "keys" you choose, opening a recordset in this entity framework.  Then process the contents of the recordset.

Comment: ah okay... so this is what you do in OPENJPA. Thank you very much. I will do as advised by you.